# vb.net dataview populated by sql

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable, dataview

I'm trying to load the data from an sql query into a datatable which will load a GridView. See code below...

```
    Dim dv As New System.Data.DataView
    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable

    dv = SQL_Week.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    dt = dv.ToTable()

    GV_WeekData.DataSource = dt
    GV_WeekData.DataBind()
```

If I run this code the Gridview appears empty. If I debug the code, when I get to dv = SQL_Week, I can pull the sql statement and if I run it in sql server I get the data that I need, but if I look at the contents of 'dv' it show a reference to 11 columns .

If I add the following code I can actually see that there is data in the datatable.
          Dim test As String = dt(1)(1)

The funny thing is that in another page, similar query and code works perfectly. It is driving me mad

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With the below code

```
GV_WeekData.AutoGenerateColumns = True
GV_WeekData.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Mandeep, thanks for your response. Unfortunatelly this doens't work. The columns seem to be there, it is the rows that don't, as per what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I re-started Visual studio and now it is populating the Gridview

You will have to forgive me. I don't understand the reason for this erratic behaviour of visual Studio